# Mongoose Boolean validation not useful if a String is provided

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose

for easier validation of my input, **I tried to ensure that a mongoose-document can only be created, if a specific field is set to true** (This field, is of course always true, IF the document was actually created properly, that's for reporting reasons).

This is a simplified poc:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/playground')

var Schema = mongoose.Schema

var TestSchema = new Schema({
  testField: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true
  }
})

// Try to ensure, that testField can only be true
TestSchema
  .path('testField')
  .validate(function (testField) {
    return (testField === true || testField === 'true')
  }, 'Test-field must be true!');

var Test = mongoose.model('test', TestSchema);


var newDoc = Test({
  testField: 'some random string'
})

newDoc.save(function (err, newDoc) {
  (err) ? console.log(err): console.log('newDoc was created')
})
```

The problem is, that even though I am supplying a random string instead of a Boolean value or "Boolean string" (e.g. "false" or "true" instead of just false/true), the document is still being saved properly, with the flag set to true.

If I supply "false" or false, the validation works properly and throws an error.

Apparently, there is some sort of type-casting, before the validation (and apparently also the defaults-action) is actually being called. Is there a way for me to fix my validation, or do I have to check the object explicitly, before creating the Mongoose-Object?

This is mongoose 4.3.6.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet? Same type coercion happens before validation with all property types...

Comment: No, not yet. Only a workaround, where I parse/validate the string before passing it to the Schema-validation...

Comment: I'm having two layers of validation aswell. One to sanitize the database on the database layer using mongoose and one to validate input on the endpoint layer. Trying to reuse validation logic. Don't like it, though. Still unsure if we should really need two layers of validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that borders on hackery, but it should work:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Schema.Types.Boolean.convertToFalse = new Set([false]);
mongoose.Schema.Types.Boolean.convertToTrue = new Set([true]);
```

Remember to set these immediately after the first require, and keep an eye on the cache.

Relevant documentation:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#booleans

Turns our Mongoose casts five different things to bool, even with strict schemas. Really grinds my gears.

Comment: xD Thanks mate, I don't even work at the company where I had this problem anymore, but I like the Set approach :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can change type Boolean to String and validate like that

```
        testField: {
            type : String,
            required: true,
            validate: {
                validator: function (value) {
                    return value === "true"
                },
                message: 'Field must be true'
            }
        }
```